# Microsoft Exchange Services - How to get exact match using Resolve

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

Here is a question related to a Microsoft Exchange-integration.
I am calling the Microsoft Exchange Services-method `ResolveName (string)`:

I am passing in a username, e.g. `myusername` , and I get two matches -one match with the username `myusername` and one with `myusername2`.
Now the question is: Is there any possibility to do a call that only returns direct matches, so that only matches with the exact username are returned?

Here follows the code:
:

```
var service = Service.GetService();

                username = Regex.Replace(username, ".*\\\\(.*)", "$1", RegexOptions.None);

                var resolvedNames = service.ResolveName(username);

                foreach (var resolvedName in resolvedNames)
                {
                    mailboxname = resolvedName.Mailbox.Address;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

That method actually resolves e-mail addresses, so for an exact match you'd need to do something like this.

```
string username = "myUserName";
string domain = "myDomain.com";
string emailAddress = username + "@" + domain;
NameResolutionCollection resolvedContactList = _service.ResolveName(emailAddress);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot specify the 'username' any further than `myusername` (as Amicable's answer assumes you can do) then the only thing to do is write a wrapper around ResolveName that *again* matches all results against your search string, this time requiring an exact match.

And for doing so you would have to parse the domain name off again, because you get the full primary SMTP email address returned in `.Mailbox.Address`.

I'm doing the exact same thing in my Delphi code ;-)